# Vertically align a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are three buttons (button 1, button 2 and button 3) in a flexbox (`myflex`).

How can I put this flexbox at the bottom of the screen and center it horizontally?

I can center it, but not put it at the bottom of the screen and make it a sticky footer.

```css
#myflex {
  display: flex;
  //position:fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myflex">
  <button class="button button1">button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">button 2</button>
  <button class="button button3">button 33</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fredericmarcel/7ssq32te/3/

Answer (score 1):

In order to move an element vertically, the container must have extra height.

Unlike width, which block elements fill 100% by default, heights must be defined. Otherwise, elements default to `auto` – the height of the content.

In your code, there is no height specified, so your flex container has no extra space for alignment. For an illustration, set borders around the `body` element and your container:

```css
body {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 1px;
}

#myflex {
  display: flex;
  bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myflex">
  <button class="button button1">button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">button 2</button>
  <button class="button button3">button 33</button>
</div>
```

Once you have the height issue resolved, you can use flex keyword properties or  [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) to center-align the flex container at the bottom.

***Method 1: Flex Keyword Properties***

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="myflex">
  <button class="button button1">button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">button 2</button>
  <button class="button button3">button 33</button>
</div>
```

***Method 2: Flex Auto Margins***

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#myflex {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="myflex">
  <button class="button button1">button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">button 2</button>
  <button class="button button3">button 33</button>
</div>
```

OR, if you want the footer to remain fixed on the screen, try this:

***Method 3: Fixed Positioning***

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#myflex {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="myflex">
  <button class="button button1">button 1</button>
  <button class="button button2">button 2</button>
  <button class="button button3">button 33</button>
</div>
```

---